# Random points on raster stack and extract values 500 times store as a list

Tags: random, extract, raster, points

I want to extract values from a raster stack "stack.r" using randomly generated 100 points, and repeat it for 20 times and store as a list.

Comment: Show us ze code

Comment: see `?raster::extract`. If that does not help you, please provide a simple example with data and code (see  the examples in `?raster::extract`)

Comment: This worked for me. p.a <- replicate(20, randomPoints(habitat.rr, 100)) # array p.a.list=lapply(seq(dim(p.a)[3]), function(x) p.a [ , , x]) # list